# Importing VMware drive into VirtualBox drive

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, import

I have VMware on my Mac and it crashed. I am unable to access the files used by the VMware. So I downloaded VirtualBox and when I try to add the .vmwarevm file to VirtualBox it says that its unable to read that type.

I wasn't sure if there was a way i can get to these files as they are extremely important.
I can not shutdown or open my virtual state in VMware whatsoever.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox can run VMs created by VMware Workstation or Server for this you need to import vmdk files using the following procedure

```
* Start Virtual Box

* Goto File > Virtual Disk Manager

* Click Add.  Locate and select the copied .vmdk file. Click OK.

* Create a New VM as usual using the added vmdk file

* Boot the VM
```

Comment: Where is my .vdk file located?
I was only able to find a .vmwarevm file in users/documents/virutal machines/windowsxp.vmwarevm

Comment: I figured out how to access my VMDK however since my VMWare crashed on it its not booting in virtualbox

Comment: I am not sure if these guys and or gals are getting it...the extension from the Mac VM is .vmwarevm and not vmdk.  I am running into this exact problem as we speak/.

Comment: I also just have a .vmwarevm file, if I mount it, then I see a mounted vmdk drive...furthermore there is no "Add" button on the Virtual Media Manager... any ideas?

Comment: Im using VirtualBox 4.04.  It doesn't have a "Add" button in the Virtual Disk Manager.  What do I do then?

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the '.vmwarevm' file in Mac OSX Finder. Select "Show Package Contents". Copy the '.vmdk' file to main directory.
Open VirtualBox, Create New Machine (from menu, select Machine -> New...) give a name, select appropriate Operating System, click [Continue], set Memory size and [Continue], and in the Hard Drive settings, select 'Use an existing virtual hard drive file' and select the '.vmdk' file that you extracted.

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to open the vmdk file that resides INSIDE the vmwarevm 'file', which is actually a folder. Rightclick it (You might need to press command) and click 'Show Package Contents'.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install qemu
qemu-img convert /path/to/your.vmdk intermediatefile.bin
VBoxManage convertdd intermediatefile.bin converted.vdi
```

Qemu can convert between Vdisk formats, but what might be worth doing would be to NOT try booting off the disk once you get it in VBox; mount the disk but boot of a mounted iso image like knoppix or a ubuntu livecd and see if the data is still on the disk. Then follow the usual troubleshooting format for 'non-booting systems'